# ERROR after update: ... exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I was updated xcode today.
When I want to show some viewController (without collectionView & tableView), I’ve got crash in AppDelegate and debug info:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:’

Anyone solved this problem?

Comment: And the failing code is?

Comment: Problem solved. It was an InputMask framework-object in .xib file

Answer (score 0):

Check your ViewController for injected Object references. It may be caused by external class from some Pod Repository. Remove it and define all the logic inside the VC class. This solved the issue for me. [VC Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m0Ie.png)